# Pandas pd.Grouper trouble with sum()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After reading and benefiting a lot from Stackoverflow over the last 6 months, now, I come across a problem that I need to ask. Very exciting.

Let me briefly state my problem:

I have a dataframe like this names "trades" (this is trading data from an exchange websocket):

```
trades.head()
                                side    price   size
date            
2019-12-26 10:20:11.895999908   buy     7210.0  1.0
2019-12-26 10:20:20.477999926   buy     7210.0  1.0
2019-12-26 10:20:21.221999884   buy     7210.0  10000.0
2019-12-26 10:20:23.737999916   sell    7210.0  1.0
```

What I desired was to two things: 
1 - Arrange data in minutes 
2-  Grouped that data for "side" and "price" information and get the cumulative "order sizes" for each "price" for any given minute.

You can look at the example below to see what I want to achieve.

```
trades.head()

date                    side    price   size

2019-12-26 10:20:00     buy     7210.0  22923.0
                        sell    7209.5  25000.0
2019-12-26 10:21:00     buy     7210.0  79432.0
                        sell    7209.5  5858.0
2019-12-26 10:22:00     buy     7210.0  76128.0
                        sell    7209.5  12307.0
2019-12-26 10:23:00     buy     7210.0  4016.0
                        sell    7209.5  25311.0
2019-12-26 10:26:00     buy     7210.0  100714.0
                        sell    7209.5  1301.0
```

I managed to get this format by using this:

```
df = trades.groupby(by=[pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq="1min"), pd.Grouper(key="side"), pd.Grouper(key="price")]).sum()
```

However, I came across with a problem:

When I try to see the largest order sizes for given side and price with

```
df.nlargest(3, 'size')
```

I get this:

```
date                    side    price   size
2019-12-31 15:21:00     buy     7172.5  5042595.0
2019-12-31 17:51:00     buy     7124.5  5027804.0
2019-12-26 16:32:00     sell    7273.5  4996261.0
```

But when I simply resample data with

```
pd.DataFrame(trades["size"].resample("1min").sum()).nlargest(3, 'size'):
```

here is what I get

```
date                    size
2019-12-27 13:00:00     46486868.0
2019-12-30 00:13:00     36092742.0
2019-12-26 19:54:00     32839185.0
```

totally different numbers and when I check the exchange's site I see that the "resample" method gives the correct numbers.

pd.Groupby way doesn't give me the right answer.

How can I get the correct numbers in my desired formatting.

P.S. - Phew! it took nearly 30 minutes for me to write this question. When I was just reading the pages it was seemed too easy. So, I will truly appreciate any comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I realized nothing is wrong with both ways.

Resample method was giving the whole sizes regardless of "price" and "side", as a result it gets larger, however Pd.Grouper way was giving more detailed information on given minute.

So everything is fine. I hope it becomes helpful for someone in future. 
See you in the next question. :)